# HashMap match against Object value

Tags: java

I'm making a text-based adventure game in Java, and I want to be able to match the player location with the location of a character/enemy. My list of characters is imported from a text file and put into a Hashmap. The importing from a text file is a requirement.

I can match the location if I specify the value (name) of the character, but I want to be able to have it go through and match on the "location" property of the character. Here is what I have:

Character object:

```
Character(String name, String location, int maxHp, int maxAttackDmg, String description)
```

Character HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, Character> characters = ReadIn.createCharacters();
```

`ReadIn.createCharacters()` parses a text file for the character properties.

There is another method called `player.getLocation()` which gives the player's current location.

Here is what I have working:

```
if (player.getLocation().equals(skeleton.getLocation()) && skeleton.getDefeated() == false) {
        Encounter e = new Encounter();
        e.fight(player,skeleton);
    }
```

If the player is in the same location as the character, and the character has not been defeated, then call the fight() method.

What I want to do is this:

```
if (player.getLocation().equals(any location in the character HashMap) {
        Encounter e = new Encounter();
        e.fight(player,<matched character from HashMap>);
    }
```

I know what I want to do, I just don't know how to do it in Java. I'm quite new to Java and programming in general. Hopefully I gave enough detail, but I can provide more if needed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does the key represent in the Character hashmap? Is that the name of the character?

Comment: `characters.values().parallelStream().map(Character::getLocation).filter(loc->loc.equals(player.getLocation())).anyMatch()`

Comment: Whatever @dan1st has suggested should solve your problem. The reason why I am commenting on your question is different. You should not create a class with the same name as that of one in Java's standard library, **and especially if it is in `java.lang` e.g. `java.lang.Character`**. Believe me, it will create a total mess.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that Character was part of Java's standard library. Thanks @Arvind Kumar Avinash for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional way to achieve this in Java would be:

```
for (Character character: characters.values()) {
    if (character.getLocation().equals(player.getLocation())
            && !character.getName().equals(player.getName())
            && !character.isDefeated()) {
        ... fight ...
    }
}
```

The alternative using streams would be:

```
characters.values().stream()
    .filter(ch -> ch.getLocation().equals(player.getLocation()))
    .filter(ch -> !ch.getName().equals(player.getName()))
    .filter(ch -> !ch.isDefeated())
    .forEach(ch -> ... fight ...);
```

If you want a single encounter irrespective of the number of characters with the same location then replace `forEach` with

```
    .findAny()
    .ifPresent(ch -> ... fight ...);
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to implement the first way you mentioned and it worked how I wanted it to. I didn't think to look into for loops.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your characters map is a "location to character map"

then use this

```
    Character matchingCharacter = characters.get(player.getLocation());
        
    if (matchingCharacter != null) {
        Encounter e = new Encounter();
        e.fight(player, matchingCharacter);
    }
```